# Implementing Promises in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, testing

I'm attempting to implement some `http.get()` requests in an angular service, returning a promise.

Here is the excerpt from my initial service:

```
angular.module('dashboard').service('DashboardHTTP', ['$q', '$http', function ($q, $http) {

    this.get_info = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('/dashboard/4/api/info', { cache: true }).success(function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).error(function () {
            deferred.reject('Could Not Complete Request');
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}]);
```

And here is an excerpt from the portion of my controller where I call the service:

```
DashboardHTTP.get_info().then(
   function (response) {
       var resp = response;
       $rootScope.dash_info = resp;
   },
   function (response) {
       return 'error';
   },
   function (response) {
       return 'notify';
   });
```

My questions:

1. I'm struggling with determining how much testing is needed for an interaction like this. I currently have the following test, which is testing at the service level, but I'm wondering if I need to test at the controller level and if so what sort of testing needs to occur?

   ```
   beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, $injector) {
       service = $injector.get('DashboardHTTP');
       $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
   }));

   afterEach(function () {
       $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
       $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
   });

   describe('get_info', function () {
       it(' should get info from the url /api/info', function () {
           var returnData = { data: 'lots of data' };
           $httpBackend.expectGET('/dashboard/4/api/info').respond(returnData);

           var returnedPromise = service.get_info();

           var result;
           returnedPromise.then(function (response) {
               result = response;
           });

           $httpBackend.flush();

           expect(result).toEqual(returnData);
       });
   });
   ```
2. My goal is that I want to set `$rootScope.dash_info` to the response from the HTTP request made by `Service.get_info()`. Is my implementation in my controller appropriate? If so, how do I test that the correct data is being passed in at the controller level?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a partial answer, but here's my input:

Your call is asynchronous, therefore your test should be. Use `done`.

```
it(' should get info from the url /api/info', function (done) {
    var returnData = { data: 'lots of data' };
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/dashboard/4/api/info').respond(returnData);

    var returnedPromise = service.get_info();

    var result;
    returnedPromise.then(function (response) {
        result = response;

        expect(result).toEqual(returnData);

        done();
    });

    $httpBackend.flush();
});
```

Also, you do know that http.get returns a promise, right? It has also `success` and `error` functions, but it is still a promise.